# How to evaluate a complex expression tree against incremental data?

Tags: algorithm, expression-trees, evaluation

I have a collection of data and a collection of search filters I want to run against that data.  The filters follow the LDAP search filter format and are parsed into an expression tree.  The data is read one item at a time and processed through all the filters.  Intermediate match results are stored in each leaf node of the tree until all the data has been processed.  Then the final results are obtained by traversing the tree and applying the logical operators to each leaf node's intermediate result.  For example, if I have the filter `(&(a=b)(c=d))` then my tree will look like this:

```
root = "&"
    left = "a=b"
    right = "c=d"
```

So if `a=b` and `c=d` then both the left and right child nodes are a match and thus the filter is a match.

The data is a collection of different types of objects, each with their own fields.  For example, assume the collection represents a class at a school:

```
class { name = "math" room = "12A" }
teacher { name = "John" age = "35" }
student { name = "Billy" age = "6" grade = "A" }
student { name = "Jane" age = "7" grade = "B" }
```

So a filter might look like `(&(teacher.name=John)(student.age>6)(student.grade=A))` and be parsed like so:

```
root = "&"
    left = "teacher.name=John"
    right = "&"
        left = "student.age>6"
        right = "student.grade=A"
```

I run the `class` object against it; no matches.  I run the `teacher` object against it; `root.left` is a match.  I run the first `student` node against it; `root.right.right` is a match.  I run the second `student` node against it; `root.right.left` is a match.  Then I traverse the tree and determine that all nodes matched and thus the final result is a match.

The problem is the intermediate matches need to be constrained based upon commonality: the `student.age` and `student.grade` filters need to somehow be tied together in order to store an intermediate match only if they match for the same object.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

My filter node abstract base class:

```
class FilterNode
{
public:
    virtual void Evaluate(string ObjectName, map<string, string> Attributes) = 0;
    virtual bool IsMatch() = 0;
};
```

I have a `LogicalFilterNode` class that handles logical AND, OR, and NOT operations; it's implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
void LogicalFilterNode::Evaluate(string ObjectName, map<string, string> Attributes)
{
    m_Left->Evaluate(ObjectName, Attributes);
    m_Right->Evaluate(ObjectName, Attributes);
}

bool LogicalFilterNode::IsMatch()
{
    switch(m_Operator)
    {
    case AND:
        return m_Left->IsMatch() && m_Right->IsMatch();
    case OR:
        return m_Left->IsMatch() || m_Right->IsMatch();
    case NOT:
        return !m_Left->IsMatch();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then I have a `ComparisonFilterNode` class that handles the leaf nodes:

```
void ComparisonFilterNode::Evaluate(string ObjectName, map<string, string> Attributes)
{
    if(ObjectName == m_ObjectName) // e.g. "teacher", "student", etc.
    {
        foreach(string_pair Attribute in Attributes)
        {
            Evaluate(Attribute.Name, Attribute.Value);
        }
    }
}

void ComparisonFilterNode::Evaluate(string AttributeName, string AttributeValue)
{
    if(AttributeName == m_AttributeName) // e.g. "age", "grade", etc.
    {
        if(Compare(AttributeValue, m_AttributeValue) // e.g. "6", "A", etc.
        {
            m_IsMatch = true;
        }
    }
}

bool ComparisonFilterNode::IsMatch() { return m_IsMatch; }
```

How it's used:

```
FilterNode* Root = Parse(...);
foreach(Object item in Data)
{
    Root->Evaluate(item.Name, item.Attributes);
}
bool Match = Root->IsMatch();
```

Essentially what I need is for AND statements where the children have the same object name, the AND statement should only match if the children match for the same object.

Comment: I've only read up to "The problem is the intermediate matches need to be constrained based upon commonality" so far, but it seems to me that you're not doing what you say sentence #3, "The data is read one item at a time and processed through all the filters".  Just do that!  You want to test *each element* of the collection, right?  In that case, you don't want or need to keep any state around between elements!  You want an outermost loop that iterates over each item in the collection, applies the entire expression tree to each, and gets a yes or no answer saying whether to keep that item.

Comment: No.  A filter can contain expressions for multiple types of elements.  I'm only reading one element at a time, which can be either a `teacher` or `student`.  A filter like `teacher.name=John AND student.grade=A` is never going to match a single element.

Comment: If a filter can contain expressions for multiple types of elements, then I don't understand what you're trying to do.  E.g. how do you know what teacher corresponds to what children?  "Filtering" usually means "choosing a subset of items", where each item is considered independently of the others.

Comment: The teacher and student was a poor example to use because the actual data elements are not related to each other.  An inventory of different types of parts would have been a better example.  Filter is probably also the wrong word.  I want to determine if there exists in the set of data a group of elements that match a criteria.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're trying to do now.  I'll put my suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new unary "operator", let's call it `thereExists`, which:

1. *Does* have state, and
2. Declares that its child subexpression must be satisfied by a single input record.

Specifically, for each instance of a `thereExists` operator in an expression tree you should store a single bit indicating whether or not the subexpression below this tree node has been satisfied by any of the input records seen so far.  These flags will initially be set to `false`.

To continue processing your dataset efficiently (i.e. input record by input record, without having to load the entire dataset into memory), you should first preprocess the query expression tree to pull out a list of all instances of the `thereExists` operator.  Then as you read in each input record, test it against the child subexpression of each of these operators that still has its `satisfied` flag set to `false`.  Any subexpression that is now satisfied should toggle its parent `thereExists` node's `satisfied` flag to `true` -- and it would be a good idea to also attach a copy of the satisfying record to the newly-satisfied `thereExists` node, if you want to actually see more than a "yes" or "no" answer to the overall query.

You only need to evaluate tree nodes above a `thereExists` node *once*, after all input records have been processed as described above.  Notice that anything referring to properties of an individual record *must* appear somewhere beneath a `thereExists` node in the tree.  Everything above a `thereExists` node in the tree is only allowed to test "global" properties of the collection, or combine the results of `thereExists` nodes using logical operators (AND, OR, XOR, NOT, etc.).  Logical operators themselves can appear anywhere in the tree.

Using this, you can now evaluate expressions like

```
root = "&"
    left = thereExists
        child = "teacher.name=John"
    right = "|"
        left = thereExists
            child = "&"
                left = "student.age>6"
                right = "student.grade=A"
        right = thereExists
            child = "student.name = Billy"
```

This will report "yes" if the collection of records contains both a teacher whose name is "John" and either a student named "Billy" or an A student aged over 6, or "no" otherwise.  If you track satisfying records as I suggested, you'll also be able to dump these out in the case of a "yes" answer.

You could also add a second operator type, `forAll`, which checks that its subexpression is true for *every* input record.  But this is probably not as useful, and in any case you can simulate `forAll(expr)` with `not(thereExists(not(expr)))`.

Comment: Couldn't you just eliminate the `thereExists` nodes and store the `satisfied` flag in the logical operator nodes (in addition to my current `m_IsMatch` implementation)?  In any case, this would require the tree to be organized by object type.  Currently the parser is naive and builds the tree in the order in which the expressions are parsed.  I wouldn't know how to go about normalizing the tree, if it is even possible.

Comment: @Luke: You can't eliminate `thereExists` altogether, because if you did, how would you be able to tell whether a subexpression is supposed to be true for a single record, or is allowed to be made true by multiple records?  E.g. in my example, the `|` is combining subexpressions that span multiple input records, while the most-nested `&` is combining subexpressions that must apply to the same record.

Comment: @Luke: An example of why you can't eliminate it is that "Does there exist a student with grade A and age > 6?" is a different query from "Does there exist a student with grade A and a student with age > 6?" are different queries.  Without `thereExists`, how would you encode these 2 queries differently?

Comment: I am still thinking in the way I am currently processing them.  You are right for the method you described above.  But the problem still remains: how do you ensure the tree is properly ordered?  For example, `(teacher.name=John AND (student.age>6 AND student.grade=A))` and `((teacher.name=John AND student.age>6) AND student.grade=A)` will generate different trees but have logical equivalence.  Your method would not work for the second case since a student element would not match a teacher expression.

Comment: @Luke: The 2 queries you gave in your last comment are *logically equivalent*, because the logical operator AND is associative: `x AND (y AND z) = (x AND y) AND z` always, for all possible values of x, y and z.  Any correctly implemented query system *must* give identical answers for them.

Comment: @Luke: Rereading your last comment, I'm not sure what you're asking.  Your current way is broken, because it's *incapable of expressing* the two different queries in my 2nd comment on this answer.  You need to make it capable of expressing these 2 queries, and one way of doing that is by using my `thereExists` operator.  There may be other ways, but what is wrong with the way I'm suggesting?

Comment: Assume you have a tree of the form `((teacher.name=John AND student.age>6) AND student.grade=A)`.  Assume you have input of the form `teacher { name = John }, student { age = 0, grade = A }, student { age = 10, grade = B }`.  Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but stepping through the logic it appears your solution would tell me there is a match (a teacher with name = John and a student with both age > 6 and grade = A) when there really isn't.

Comment: @Luke: That tree is invalid in my scheme (i.e. it ought to be rejected with an error message), because (as I say in my answer) it contains a subexpression that refers to a property of an individual record (such as `teacher.name`) and which is not contained within a `thereExists` subexpression.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39932/discussion-between-luke-and-j-random-hacker)